# In Azure, how can I use API Management to forward all requests to an Azure VM on port 3000?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure

I am migrating from AWS to Azure. Here is a diagram of how things are working for my website in AWS:

[image]

For Frontend:
I am using Cloudfront + S3 bucket to host a React App frontend. Users who visits the url `https://www.myapp.com` will be visiting this cloudfront and thus loading the react app frontend in their browser.

For Backend API calls:

All requests to the backend APIs are `https://www.api.myapp.com/*` and are directed to an AWS API Gateway. The request must contain the correct token to authenticate against AWS Cognito.

All requests are forwarded to a Network Load Balancer, which then forward the request to a target group containing multiple EC2-instances. Each EC2 instance is running the identical nodejs Express app, which is the backend for my web app.

On migrating to Azure, I am thinking that I can use the same structure with Azure equivalents:

for backend:

AWS API Gateway --> Azure API Management

EC2 instance --> Azure vm

for frontend:

Amazon CloudFront --> Azure FrontDoor

S3 bucket --> Azure Blob storage

However, I have encountered some questions:

In AWS, we use API Gateway to forward all api requests to EC2 instances. We can create an api and set the HTTP verb to be "ANY" so that the forwarding operation applies to all http methods.

In Azure API management, there is no such verb "ANY".

So usually, do people just create a separate operation for each HTTP method, and each operation has the same configs? We've got:

GET

POST

PUT

DELETE ...

there are 8 of them;

There is a lot of redundancy, isn't it?

Am I wrong in the first place in assuming that I can use Azure APIM to forward requests to VMs hosting the backend?